# Hibernate two @OneToMany relation for a single entity triggers two SELECT queries before UPDATE

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 4 entity classes. ClassA is parent. ClassB and ClassC have @OneToMany association with ClassA. ClassD have @OneToOne association with ClassA.

When I trigger repository.saveAll(List classAList), for new insertion, there is no issues. The list of ClassA entities are saved to DB without any issues.

But, when I have an update scenario, the same repository.saveAll(List classAList) is called. Now, Hibernate triggers a SELECT query with join statement for ClassA, ClassB and ClassD.(Note: ClassC is not joined)

Hibernate triggers another SELECT query for ClassC which joins ClassA, ClassB,ClassD. [

```
    SELECT .. 
FROM ClassC class1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassA class2 
        ON class1.NAX_ID=class2.NAX_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassB class3 
        ON class2.NAX_ID=class3.NAX_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassD class4 
        ON class2.NAX_ID=class4.NAX_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassA class5 
        ON class4.NAX_ID=class5.NAX_ID 
WHERE class1.ID=?
```

]

Can someone help me to avoid the 2nd query which is getting triggered.

Entity Class are as below.

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "CLASS_A")
public class ClassA implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAX_ID")
    private Long naxId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="classA")
    private Set<ClassC> classCSet;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="classA")
    private ClassD classD;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="classA")
    private Set<ClassB> classBSet;

    //Setters and Getters
}

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "CLASS_B")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "classBSequence", allocationSize = 500)
public class ClassB implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="classBSequence")//uses hibernate sequence
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="NAX_ID", referencedColumnName="NAX_ID")
    private ClassA classA;

    //Setters and Getters
}

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "CLASS_C" )
@SequenceGenerator(name="classCSequence", allocationSize=500)
public class ClassC implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="classCSequence")//uses hibernate sequence
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="NAX_ID", referencedColumnName="NAX_ID")
    private ClassA classA;

    //Setters and Getters
}

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "CLASS_D")
public class ClassD implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAX_ID")
    private Long naxId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "NAX_ID", referencedColumnName = "NAX_ID")
    private ClassA classA;

    //Setters and Getters
}
```

My expectation is to have a single SELECT query joining ClassA, ClassB, ClassC and ClassD during UPDATE call. How I can achieve it ?

Comment: Hi  - Can anyone help on the above issue ?

Comment: @xtremebaumer - I have tried with the edited code as well. Still, I am seeing the 2nd query getting triggered.